# Not fetching property from application.properties | Using custom shallow health check instead of spring health check |

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, spring-boot-actuator

To disable springs shallow health check to use our own shallow health check.

When disabling actuator endpoints,

> endpoints.health.enabled=false

In my application.context

```
<bean id="imsPlaceholderConfig" class="com.xx.xxx.SpringPropertiesUtil">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>file:${config.path}/application.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

My application.properties is placed under:

> classpath:/conf/

Many properties are kept under application.properties which are used via: `@Value`

Everything works fine except this property is not read. i.e

- endpoints.health.enabled=false
- spring.profiles.active = swagger

The above two properties are not used by spring.

**Cases when it does work**

1. When running my spring boot application:

   mvn spring-boot:run -Dconfig.path=./src/main/resources/conf -Dspring.config.location=./src/main/resources/conf/application.properties

When I use spring.config.location, it picks up the value and my custom shallow health end point runs.

OR

2.when I place my application.properties under

> classpath:/

It works.

OR

3. when I use `@PropertyResource`, it works.

MY Question is, why doesn't spring pick the above mentioned property when it picks rest of the properties from the application.

**I need to understand why are these properties different from the one used by other Beans and once the application.properties have been loaded why can't spring use from there instead?**

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Please clarify. Also there is no `src/main.resources` from the perspective of a packaged/running Spring Boot application. That is the `class path:` so you are basically hacking around the defaults. So if anything you should use `-Dspring.config.location=classpath:/conf` however it is better to use `spring.config.additional-location`.

Comment: Sure, let me edit the question to explain better.

Comment: @M. Deinum I understand that using spring.config.location will provide the config file path to the spring application. But I need to understand that if I don't use spring.config.location and as second preference it checks if I have given config file path either under PropertySource or PlaceHolderConfig. I am using placeholderConfig to provide the config to spring application. But in doing so, the aboce mentioned properties are ignored/not used by spring. 
But if I use PropertySource annotation or -Dspring.config.location it picks up that property. I need to understand this behaviour!